# Couldn't find ionic.config.json file

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

when i run `ionic build android`

i get this error -

```
Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?
```

And i am in the project folder..

Anyone please?

Comment: I got rid of that error by renaming it to `ionic.config.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the recent update to the ionic-cli look for a file,
so just rename the file named `ionic.project` to `ionic.config.json`

Comment: Thanks, but now i am getting error `Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
Cannot find module 'bower'

Do you need to run `npm install`?`  But i already have bower installed globally, as when i run bower command i can see bower options and commands..so  how can i solve this error..

Comment: Ionic also requires a local copy of Bower so install it by `npm i bower` in you ionic project folder.

Comment: Yeah after i installed locally it ran successfully.. But why? also there were other modules like gulp-sass and concat i had to install locally..

Comment: Sir I will check but ionic.config file is not showing in my project stracture tell me sir what I do?

Answer (score 5):

Go to ionic.io to create a new app. Then create ionic.config.json file in your app's root folder with content like

```
{
  "name": "your_app_name",
  "app_id": "your_app_id"
}
```

Then run the command "ionic build android", it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once, all what I've come up with, is to create a new project, then replace the www folder with my own one, add all plugins. seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- For me, After created the project using this command : `ionic start
  alertDialog blank --v2`.New project was created.
- first of all check whether you have ionic.config.json file is available in that project folder.But what is the **issue** means,  I had already create one alertDialog
  folder before running the command.So the directory would be `MyIonic2-> alertDialog -> alertDialog.`
- So I removed one folder alertDialog. Now it would be `MyIonic2 ->
  alertDialog` fixed my issue.