# Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and trying to run `ionic serve` to test my application but I keep getting this error:

```
Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?
```

On running `ionic info`, I get the following:

```
 $ ionic info
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please update your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: undefined
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v4.4.5
```

Tried it with [Couldn't find ionic.config.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192030/couldnt-find-ionic-config-json-file) but couldn't resolve the issue.

I am also getting this trace while creating an application with `ionic start myApp tabs`:

```
Installing npm packages (may take a minute or two)...
Error with start Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at spawn (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\                                                            ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:17:18)
    at Object.runSpawnCommand (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\io                                                            nic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\start.js:56:17)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-a                                                            pp-lib\lib\start.js:104:20
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_mod                                                            ules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules                                                            \ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m                                                            odules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:                                                            557:44
```

Can someone please help here.

Comment: Have you checked if there is a ionic.config.json file in your project folder? If yes, can you share it?

Comment: It is not there. I tried creating it with `{
  "name": "your_app_name",
  "app_id": "your_app_id"
}` but still faced with the same error.

Comment: Easiest thing to do: Create a new project with the `ionic start` command -> Check if there's a ionic.config.json in your new project -> If yes: Try `ionic serve` again -> If no -> Your Ionic installation might be broken -> Reinstall Ionic...

Comment: Tried reinstalling it after getting errors but still getting the same error and config as shared above

Comment: Does the installation of Ionic run without errors?

Comment: Yes completely without any.

Comment: @Phonolog Please have a look..I edited my question a little.

Comment: Try installing cordova dependency using npm install -g cordova

Comment: I have installed it, uninstalled it, then reinstalled it with commands like `npm install -g cordova`,`npm uninstall -g cordova`,'npm install -g cordova@latest', but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I'm out of ideas here... You could create a issue with the new error in the [ionic repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues) to get some help.

Answer (score 7):

I think your first machine have ionic version < 2.0.0, the other one >= 2.0.0

If you found file named
`ionic.project` **rename** it to `ionic.config.json`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in my question that my ionic version is `Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1`. Plus renaming the file hasn't helped either.

Comment: It helped for me!

Answer (score 3):

Create an `ionic.config.json` file manually in your project folder. Copy below mentioned code in this file:

```json
{
  "name": "Replace with your project name",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true
}
```

perform an `npm install` to ensure all node_modules are updated. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After creating your new project, you need to step into the projects folder, in there you will find the config file and you can run ionic serve.

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
$ cd myApp
$ ionic serve
```

Be sure that you are running last version of ionic and cordova.

Comment: I am running `ionic serve` inside my project folder and getting the error. When I run `ionic info` it shows ionic version as `Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1` but along with it shows `Cordova CLI: undefined'. How can I get around the error that I am getting.

Comment: Have you tried to update npm and cordova with
$ npm install -g npm
$ npm install -g cordova

Answer (score 0):

install ionic using.

npm install -g ionic@latest

or

refer link : **http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html**

Answer (score 0):

As per logs you are getting Cordova CLI: undefined. Seems like an issue with CLI installation. Try reinstalling and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to start the fresh installation. And remove existing cordova and ionic

install cordova & ionic with `npm install -g cordova ionic`

Then install the template `ionic start --v2 myApp tabs` 
Check out this link https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here is what I did.

**Mac steps**

1. sudo npm install npm -g
2. sudo npm install -g cordova
3. Restart your computer also. I was receiving deprecated minimatch@2.0.10 warnings prior to the restart.

**Windows steps**

1. Redownload Node.js by going to [here](https://nodejs.org/)
2. After download npm and Node.js will be updated as they are packaged together in the download.
3. `sudo npm install -g cordova` in Command prompt window.
4. Run `cordova --version` to make sure you are all set
5. Restart your computer.

This should resolve the issue hopefully.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion Jet, but I am running on windows. Any alternative for that,

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and i was able to resolve my own issue with the ionic.config.json file. Try to update your graceful-fs file by running this command:

```
npm install -g graceful-fs graceful-fs@latest.
```

After running the command, try to create your project again by running the ionic start myApp. Where 'myApp is the name of the folder you want created for your project. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your node version is above v6. Then in the root of your ionic project run `ionic info`.

It should give you a prompt something like **"Looks like this is an Ionic Angular project, would you like to install @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular and continue?"**

Type `yes`

It should have ran the following command for you: `npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular@latest`

Now you can run `ionic serve` and it will work.

p.s above is from my experience, had the same issue and the above sorted it out. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not in project directory and try

```
ionic serve
```

And If you found file named `ionic.project` rename it to `ionic.config.json`