# Couldn't find ionic.config.json file inside an ionic2 project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I m running the command : ionic platform add android , and I am inside and ionic2 project , and I have the ionic.config.json file in my app :

```
{
  "name": "menu",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true
}
```

but I keep getting: Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?

Any help please ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are in the correct folder? Does `ionic serve` work as expected?

Comment: I am in the correct folder , and ionic serve gives the same thing ! Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?

Comment: did you just start this project using `ionic start ...`?

Comment: I certainly DID !

Comment: and after running `ionic start myApp ...` did you then `cd` into `myApp`?

Comment: I said I m inside the app ! so yea I did !

Comment: just making sure, perhaps one of the solutions here may work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192030/couldnt-find-ionic-config-json-file

Comment: I tried that before posting my question , but it didn't work unfortuantely :/

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is to try re-installing ionic/cordova

Comment: which directory are you in? are you in the root of your APP?

Comment: Yes , I was , and I got your point , I shoul cd in the folder where the ionic.config.json exists , because as I noticed now it's a different folder , thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't find ionic.config.json file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192030/couldnt-find-ionic-config-json-file)